# jquery send file to as3 fileReference

Tags: jquery, flash, external, filereference

i am trying to do a simple flash file uploader.
I created a flash SWF which manages to upload the file on the server and a php which saves it there. The thing i want to accomplish right now is to have this flash somewhere hidden and access it via external functions. All i want to do is to browse a file with  and to give the file to the flash fileReference via jQuery and than call fileReference.upload().

I hope someone can help me with this issue.
Thank you in advance, Daniel!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Flash file you would wan't to look at the ExternalInterface class where you'll add a callback method. Something like this:

```
if (ExternalInterface.available)
    ExternalInterface.addCallback("jsFunc", doSomething);

function doSomething():void
{
     trace("i did something");
}
```

The method jsFunc should then be callable from JS on the SWF Object. Check the [ExternalInterface documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) for further info.

Comment: However im not sure that it is possible to trigger Upload dialog without a click from within the Flash.